# In an IIf function in Access, how do I assign null values?

Tags: ms-access, null, calculated-field, iif

I'm creating a calculated field (Field3) in a query in MS Access. In this example, Field2 contains both numeric and character values. I want Field3 to contain only numeric values from Field2 and to convert all character values to Null values so that I can later perform calculations on Field3 as a numeric field. This is in an IIf function because I want Field3 to contain only values from Field2 if Field1 = "AA". This is what I tried typing in the Field row in the Query Design View:

```
Field3: IIf([Field1]="AA",[Field2]*1,NULL)
```

This works except where Field2 is a character value then Field3 reads "#Error" instead of being blank.

What is the proper syntax for assigning NULL values if the IIf condition is not met?

Comment: Maybe this is the wrong question to be asking - it appears the NULL assignment is working, but the problem is that when Field2 is character then it returns an error instead of converting to NULL.

Comment: The next time you ask a question, please try to include as much information as possible right from the beginning. The `This works except where Field2 is a character value` part *(which was added after I answered the question)* was crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the expression to return `[Field2]*1` only when [Field1]="AA" and [Field2] contains a number, but otherwise return Null, use `IsNumeric()` in the condition ...

```sql
IIf([Field1]='AA' And IsNumeric([Field2]), [Field2]*1, Null)
```

If the purpose of `[Field2]*1` is to cast the `[Field2]` text value as a number, consider the Val() function instead ...

```sql
IIf([Field1]='AA' And IsNumeric([Field2]), Val([Field2]), Null)
```

Comment: This is the answer I needed - thanks! Wasn't quite asking the right question since I wasn't sure at first where the problem was...

Answer (score 0):

`Null` **is** the correct syntax.

But at least in the old German Access version which I have on this machine, I need to use semicolons instead of commas in the Query Design View.

So can you try this?

```
Field3: IIf([Field1]="AA";[Field2]*1;NULL)
```

In SQL View, the syntax is exactly like in your question:

```
SELECT IIf([Field1]="aa",[Field2]*1,Null) AS Field3
FROM TestTable;
```

Comment: I tried it with semicolons but it gave an "invalid syntax" error. When I run the query with Field3: IIf([Field1]="AA",[Field2]*1,NULL)  it works except that instead of NULL values it produces #ERROR as the value.

Comment: Can you try switching to SQL View, modifying the `IIf` so that it looks like in my second example? If the query works then, switch back to Query Design View and you should see the correct Query Design view syntax.

Comment: Hmm....I just googled "ms access iif" and looked at some screenshots of English Access versions, and apparently [commas actually work in the English version](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/sort/query-date-sort-calculated-design.jpg) (I get a syntax error when I use commas in my German Access 2010). Which Access version in which language are you using?

Comment: In SQL view it matches your example but it still returns #ERROR values when it runs. I'm using English Access 2010 on Windows.